# What exactly is a conversation in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

Apologies if this has been already answered somewhere here, but I really can't understand/find what is the actual notion of *conversation* in Gmail.

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en):

> Gmail groups all replies with their original message, creating a single conversation or thread.

Anyway I have seen that sending two emails with the same "Merry Xmas" subject groups them in a conversation too.

Where can I find a formal definition of conversation or, put it differently,  what are the rules to group message A and B under the same conversation?

Answer (score 3):

Replies to emails and forwards of emails make up conversations.

When a subject is changed, that breaks the conversation.

For some reason, e-mails with the same title may get grouped into a conversation.

However, there isn't a way that I know of to group individual emails into a conversation.

Comment: The same-subject rule is particularly annoying. You send informal Xmas greetings to a friend and this is merged to office formal greetings. This creates a lot of confusion: people with no links appear in the same conversation. Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: Yes, @antonion. It can definitely be annoying. But I don't think there's anyway to change that. (at least currently)

Answer (score 0):

Conversation means when Mr X sent an email to Mr Y and Mr Y replied back on the same email to Mr X and continue further.

We can use labels to group similar emails.

But from best of my knowledge there is no such feature in Gmail to group two separate emails in one  conversation.

Comment: This is the Google stated rule, but see also @user4386709 answer and my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is a feature mainly useful for the business. Where emails with similar email subjects will be grouped under single mail chain. I believe that we can not change it using any settings since its comes under google default mail sorting technique

Comment: I think that in many instances it is safe to assume that those messages with an identical subject belong to the same conversation. Anyway there can be a relevant number of use-cases where this is just due to a recurring titling and we end-up matching recipients totally unrelated. I am convinced that this is a buggy feature and anyway opting out from the conversation style is not acceptable as a fix.